# How do I clear a struct if I can't use memset?

Tags: c++, memcpy

I'm working with a piece of C++ code previously compiled (for x86) with clang++. In converting to gcc, I'm seeing an error on the following line:

```
    memset(tracking, 0, sizeof(dbg_log_tracking_t));
```

I understand that I can't memset a 'non-trivial' (compiler's words) class, or something with a vtable, but this is a *struct*, it's a block of memory and nothing more, yet on compile, g++ tells me that I can't clear an object of a non-trivial type.

I'm being given a pointer as a buffer, and I will read data into that buffer from a phy, and the struct is then used to unpack. This struct needs to be zeroed before the read is done.

In C, I could happily shoot myself in the foot. I could memset main() to null if I so chose, and it's quite frustrating that I cannot do so here.

The only solution I can think of is to keep a static instance of this struct that is already zeroed, and memcpy it over, but that just seems like memset with extra steps and wasted memory.

Short of writing a clear function that hits every field of *this specific struct* (which would have to be done any time I ever want to do this), how do I zero an entire struct?

Comment: Show your struct. If it's indeed trivial, then I wouldn't expect a warning from GCC. If it's  not trivial, you can't use it for deserialization, nor can you memcpy between different instances of it (it's as bad as `memset`).

Comment: In C++ `struct`s are `class`s. The only difference you're ever likely to notice (and may be the only difference, but there's some disagreement about the niggly bits in the dark corners) is different default access permissions.

Comment: Also show the error message.

Comment: Would like to know the type of `tracking`. And the show us  the definition of this type. Does it have a constructor? Maybe what you want is the default constructor that does this work.

Comment: "In C, I could happily shoot myself in the foot. [...] it's quite frustrating that I cannot do so here." -- You find it frustrating that the compiler is warning you of an error in your code?

Comment: I don't understand.  Why not create an initialization or clear method that will clear the innards of your class or struct?  Instead of `memset`, you could do `myObject.Clear();` which is probably more readable.

Comment: The struct is trivial, and it is just a warning. The issue is that this is production code and -werror is enabled

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you are using C++ 11 or superior

```
tracking = {};
```

should work

Comment: This is how it should be done!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
memset(&tracking, 0, sizeof(dbg_log_tracking_t));
//     ^ Note ampersand
```

I am making the assumption that tracking is an instance of your struct.

i.e.

```
dbg_log_tracking_t tracking;
memset(&tracking, 0, sizeof(tracking));  // I think this is more readable
```